# How to test UITableView sliding performance?

Tags: ios

I want to see the UITableView sliding performance, like scroll velocity, memory occupy etc. Can Xcode Profiler do this? Give some numbers or graphics?

I am having a problem with UITableView, that has a UIImageView as a subview of UITableViewCell. When I set it's layer's corner property, the UITableView scroll becomes less smooth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use Instruments to collect the CPU and memory usage. You may refer to [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/AnalysingCPUUsageinYourOSXApp/AnalysingCPUUsageinYourOSXApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH16-SW1).

In your particular case, you first collect CPU usage. Then you expand the method named `scrollViewDidScroll` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, and check if any CPU demanding lines. Typically you have to complete each call within 16ms so as to maintain smooth animation at 60fps.